# Expo camera - takePictureAsync() very slow on Android

Tags: android, react-native, performance, expo, expo-camera

Hello I am trying to implement a pictures app where users can upload their pictures or capture one directly from the app itself.

On iOS everything works perfectly but on Android the function takePictureAsync from expo-camera takes a huge time to resolve and thus the app feels much slower.

I am using Expo SDK 47 and expo-camera@~12.5.0

Here is the code:

```
const camera = useRef();

const takePicture = async () => {
const image = await camera.current?.takePictureAsync({
  quality: 0.1,
  skipProcessing: true,
  base64: true
});
```

Is it possible that the base64 property could cause this function to be slow on Android?

Edit: Tested without base64, nothing changed.

Comment: Then try without base64.

Comment: @blackapps I just tested without base64 but it still really slow

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. Facing the same issue.